# Google Play testing in-app billing with open beta

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, beta

I currently have an Android app set up for beta testing in the Google Play store. It is currently a closed beta group, but I am getting ready to switch to an open beta.

My app uses a paid subscription model. It is free to download and install, but once the user reaches a certain amount of data storage, they have to buy a subscription in order to input any more data. This is working fine for my closed beta group. I entered all of my beta testers' email addresses in the "License Testing" area of the developer console, and when they "buy" the subscription, they are not actually charged.

How will this work when I move to an open beta? Since anyone can download the beta app in an open beta, I don't see as how I'd get a chance to add them to the "License Testing" area to prevent them from being charged.

How can I therefore prevent my open beta testers from having to pay for the subscription? It would surely be a slap in the face to the people who are helping me test my app to make them pay for the subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to give free access to everybody to the paid suscription you have some solutions:

1.- Ask a server if the app is in BETA and if it returns true, jump over the suscription code

2.- Remove suscription code from the BETA version and put it again in final one

3.- Open a Dialog when the user click in pay suscription and tell him about sending his email to you for you to add it in the testing accounts.

As there is no option like "Everybody are testers", this is my solution.

Sorry for my really bad English.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem with 1 and 2 is that I want the beta testers to be testing the subscription code. With #3 I wouldn't be able to prevent them from being charged before adding them to the testers list.

Comment: @JoeMjr2 Yes but if they see your dialog that they will be charged if they don't send you their email and then they pay it, they are knowing that are paying it.